# Insert link dynamically to a Shadowbox image

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I have a Wordpress Shadowbox which loads the image and the description. Description has some link in it, and I would like to place that link also on the image, so when user clicks the image it opens this link.

I tried with this script, but it has definitely some flaws: it makes the link only after clicking once the image and it doesn't unwrap the "a" so that the new links can be used for the other dynamically loaded images.

```
$("#sb-wrapper-inner").live("click", function(){
  var $link = $("#sb-title-inner a").attr("href");
$(this).wrap("<a></a>").parent("a").attr("href", $link).trigger('click');
});
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger native event as link click redirecting to href url. Obviously for security reason.
But you can still redirecting to url targeted by the href attribute.

```
$(document).on("click","#sb-wrapper-inner", function(){ 
  var link = $("#sb-title-inner a").attr("href");
$(this).wrap("<a></a>").parent("a").attr("href", link);
     window.location​​​​​​​​​​​​​ = link;​ //or use window.location.replace(link) if you dont care about browser's history
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but your solution gave me some error in Console:
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**

I improved and simplified my method like this:

```
$("#sb-wrapper-inner").live("click", function(){
if ( $("#sb-title-inner a").length > 0 ) {
  var link = $("#sb-title-inner a").attr("href");
  window.location = link;
}
});
```

Now it works fine, only that I don't have the cursor changed to pointer. 
Any suggestion how I could improve it by this?